# VI: any way to have the autocompletion feature that there is on the command line (you know pushing tab..)?

Tags: editor, vi

any way to have the autocompletion feature for paths that there is on the linux command line (you know pushing tab..)?

Regards

Javi

Comment: Are we talking about plain vi, or vim, or...?

Comment: vi, vim or any other linux shell editor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Vim 7, use <kbd>CTRL-X</kbd><kbd>CTRL-F</kbd>. See `:help i_CTRL-X_CTRL-F` ore more globally the whole paragraph on completion: `:help ins-completion`.